# where="1234" not equal to where=1234

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

This might be an easy question for the sql pros here:
How could it possibly be that following queries with a database (one field `varchar(30)`), get different results:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field=1234;
```

returns:

```
1234
1234
```

and

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field="1234";
```

returns:

```
1234
```

So, the first query seems to return the result 1234 two times, whether the second one returns the result only one time. The data in the database is unknown. To make it even more upset, the field "field" in the database has a unique key.

Thanks!

Comment: No, not really. When I look at the two results, I can't see any spaces.

Comment: Don't trust the eyes. Try `SELECT field, length(field), md5(field) FROM table WHERE field=1234;` and post the results.

Comment: Are you using a real RDBMS or a toy one, like MySQL?

Comment: Tried that. Length and md5 hash is the same... I'm using MySQL.

Comment: It should have added (to make it even more upset), that the field "field" in the database has a unique index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you trust the OP, *a database (one field `varchar(30)`)*

Comment: Character values have to be enclosed in single quotes `'1234'`. Double quotes are used to denote identifiers.

Comment: @horse, that doesn't explain the two results when comparing to a number

Comment: @SteveP: but the column in question is a `varchar`

Comment: @charihans: please create a SQLFiddle example to show this.

Comment: @charihans, or dump the table.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem oO When I dump the data and reimport or try to create a fiddle, the unique key says that it is not allowed to insert duplicate data into that field.. So, it seems that there is something with the index in my database wrecked up? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that field is a string, and two rows contain these values

```
1234
1234.0
```

Both of these will compare true to numerical 1234.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: The output would have contained `1234.0` though.

Comment: Hmmm, need to think some more

Answer (score 0):

First case "1234" is the correct one since the field value will not accept duplicated values.

To make sure there is no bug or system errors:

try to apply the same thing on a new table with few values in it. make the column Unique...and apply a query with "" and without "" .

The result should return One value only in the first case with "".

Regards

Comment: Yeah, but why do I get two results with the first query?

Comment: Can you try this query and tell us about the result for both cases with "" and without "" :
SELECT sum(field) as FieldTest FROM table WHERE field=1234;

Comment: Without "" it returns me 1235 and 1235 and with "" it returns me 1235.

Comment: that should never happen your field type is varchar ..how come it can add 1 to the value

Comment: actually `"1234"` is a column name ("identifier"). String literals need to be enclosed in **single** quotes: `'1234'` is a varchar value.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this would be correct in PostgreSQL, say, but MySQL allows either.

Comment: But it happens... It adds 1 to the result and the column has definitely varchar(30) as data type.

Comment: @Koterpillar: it depends on the SQL mode. In ANSI mode a double quote will denote an identifier.

Comment: @charihans: what happens if you use single quotes (as it should be)?

Comment: SELECT sum(field)... returns me without "" 2468 and with "" 1234.

Comment: With single quotes I get an one result.

Comment: @charihans: using `sum()` on a `varchar` column makes absolutely no sense. The values are always returned without quotes from the database.

Comment: I only made this because Rebo Koye suggested it a few comments up.

Comment: Yes, but i am still trying to figure that problem..it's really weird. I think it's a system problem on your machine only.

Comment: It seems so.. Take a look at my last comment on my initial post.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to check is there duplicate value in database or is it just in result? Maybe you can return ASCII code for both rows in result, and compare it...